# Call Shopify api in laravel with Particular shopify store data?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

1. shopify public api in laravel Php. Run app to this type error show in laravel 7

Comment: where is the error, Please add details to your question to be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public API
This assumes you properly have your app setup in the partner's dashboard with the correct keys and redirect URIs.

REST (sync)
For REST calls, the shop domain and access token are required.

```
use Osiset\BasicShopifyAPI\BasicShopifyAPI;
use Osiset\BasicShopifyAPI\Options;
use Osiset\BasicShopifyAPI\Session;

// Create options for the API
$options = new Options();
$options->setVersion('2020-01');

// Create the client and session
$api = new BasicShopifyAPI($options);
$api->setSession(new Session('example.myshopify.com', 'access-token-here'));

// Now run your requests...
$result = $api->rest(...);
```